# Measure capacity of Lithium by Coulomb counter method while charging

Tags: batteries

I'm learning to design a module to measure capacity (percent left) of ebike Lithium battery. Lithium cell ' specifications are 48V-13Ah, it's built from cell pin 18650- 2600mAh. I choose the Coulomb counter method to measure SOC. As the photo below:

Step 1: Initially, K1 and K2 open. When I connect the battery, K1 closes and K2 opens. Discharge current will be calculated by hall sensor for a short time (~3s) and the duration from K1 close will also be counted too. So, it means left percent of the battery is:

```
 %battery_1= (Ct - Cd)/Ct ; which Ct(Ah) is 13Ah, Cd(Ah) is discharge current x time
```

Step 2: K1 opens, K2 closes. The battery is charged from the adapter, charge current is also calculated through hall sensor integrating with the time.

```
 %battery_2 = %battery_1 + Cc/Ct ; which Cc() is charge current x time
```

[image: diagram]
This is my method I intend to measure %battery while charging. I hope someone can give me some recommendations about it. Thank of all you.

Answer (score 1):

The process is a tad more complicated than that.

1. The %battery is not an absolute value, it is a dynamic value. You need to keep a current running tally of the charge in the battery and its current capacity. If you start counting the outgoing current at 72% capacity then your first formula does not work.
2. The battery may have more or less capacity than 13Ah. You also need to keep track of what that capacity is. This will degrade over time. The algorithm needs to cross check the voltage of the battery vs its current capacity. If the voltage shows discharged but the battery is at 30% then the total capacity needs to be adjusted. This is further compounded by the fact that draining the battery to its low voltage cut off is not practical and so voltage readings need to be taken all across the full range of the battery.

Comment: why can not use the first formula at 72 %?

Comment: @ThanhniênYênBái Nothing in your formula implies that something is cumulatively stored over time to keep track of the current state. If you start from 100% and subtract current x time that makes sense. Your formula makes that assumption by subtracting from the theoretical total, or 100%. If the battery is at 72% to start with, current x time no longer makes sense.